# keeping html entitles when using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I'm trying to keep html entitles while parsing an html page.
Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>{"key": "my &quot;value&quot;" }</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Heres my python (2.7.11) code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = open("test.html", "r").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
```

for
`print soup.div`
result will be `<div>{"key": "my "value"" }</div>`

for `print soup.div.get_text()` result will be `{"key": "my "value"" }`

For both cases I'm losing `&quot;`. Is there any way to keep it while using BeautifulSoup, especially when using get_text()?

Because next I want to parse the text into json.
so when I use `json.dumps(soup.div.get_text())` it's not working.

Comment: See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#entities

Comment: I've seen that but in case of my div will be `<div>&gt;&quot;Test&quot;Here is another "Test"</div>` I won't be able to know which one was `&quot;` and which one was original `"`.

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: Because the text I'm getting is a json. and when I'm trying to use json.loads(string) it fails because of a string like that {"key": "my &quot;value&quot;" }

Comment: addition to my comment: because of the beautifulsoup will replace it to: `{"key": "my "value"" }` and when I will replace every `"` to `&quot;` it will convert it to invalid JSON. I hope now it's more clear